# Why Do I Get Syntax Error Using Colon as Seperator in Array Formulas

Tags: excel

I get compile syntax error or compile error: Expected: list seperator or Expected:) in formulas to find last row from Stackoverflow #5441885

See Stackoverflow ticket 5441885 with several formulas to find last row. I've tested the first 4 listed formulas and none work.  Where there is a colon ":" in the formula I get compile errors that say Syntax Error or Expected: list seperator) or Expected:).  And I do use clt-shift-enter for array formulas.

```
lRMon = INDEX(A:A,MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A))))
lRMon =LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),A:A)
lRMon = LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:A65535<>""),A1:A65535)
lRMon =OFFSET($A$1;COUNTA(A:A)-1;0)
```

These are the first 4 formulas listed

Thanks for any help.